# Generic entity management class JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

Hello my fellow programmers!

I'm working on a school assignment, which basically involves generating HTML through Servlets - and communicating with a database (postgreSQL) through JPA. Everything **works** as intended, however, I created a class to manage my entities through EntityMangerFactory etc:

```
package no.hib.dat104.database;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.RollbackException;

public class Management<T> {

EntityManagerFactory factory;
EntityManager em;
EntityTransaction transaction;

public Management(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
    em = factory.createEntityManager();
    transaction = em.getTransaction();
}

public List<Message> retrieveMessages() {
    transaction.begin();
    TypedQuery q = 
            em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Mesage m", Message.class);
    List<Message> res = q.getResultList();
    transaction.commit();
    return res;
}

public void update(T entity) {
    transaction.begin();
    em.refresh(entity);
    transaction.commit();
}

public void add(T entity) {
    transaction.begin();
    em.persist(entity);
    transaction.commit();
}

//reference point ONE)
public Person retrievePerson(Integer id) {
    transaction.begin();
    TypedQuery q = 
            em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id = :var");
    q.setParameter("var", id);
    List<Person> result = q.getResultList();
    transaction.commit();
    return result.size() > 0 ? result.get(0) : null;
}

//reference point TWO)
//public Person retrievePerson(Integer id) {
//  transaction.begin();
//  TypedQuery q = 
//          em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id = :var");
//  q.setParameter("var", id);
//  Person result = q.getSingleResult();
//  transaction.commit();
//  return result;
//}

public Person retrievePerson(String name) {
    transaction.begin();
    TypedQuery q = 
            em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :var");
    q.setParameter("var", name);
    List<Person> result = q.getResultList();
    transaction.commit();
    return result.size() > 0 ? result.get(0) : null;
}
}
```

And I find this class not so very effective. My servlet instantiates two references to Management.java:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEnetityMangagerFactory("openjpa"); 
Management<Message> maM = new Management<Message>(factory);
Management<Person> maP = new Management<Person>(factory);
```

So:
**Question 1):** Is there any way to re-factor this (Management.java) code to make it more <strike>efficient</strike> generic?
**Question 2):** I commented two reference points, ONE) and TWO) in the class. TWO) throws <strike>NullPointerException</strike> NoResultException if nothing is found. Which one do you find most efficient? Or is there a better solution?

Any replies or comments is "much-ly" appreciated - sorry my english :)

Comment: I think you should read up on DAO pattern (which is more or less what you're doing). Also, while the code could use some refactoring I don't know what you mean by "efficient" - database queries like this won't get any faster

Comment: You're probably right, thanks. I meant something like "more generic" - hard time formulating myself.

Comment: Reference point TWO) can not throw `NullPointerException`. It should throw `javax.persistence.NoResultException` when there is no row that matches specified criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-implementation-patterns - that should get you through Generic DAO creation process. Important highlights:

- using EJB or Spring could let you get rid of that ugly factory passing in constructor and could take care of transaction handling.
- you need generic class that will serve as a basis for all concrete-class DAOs. That will probably include generic add, remove, findById, refresh and findAll
- for each entity (Message, Person) you create a subclass of the generic class. It will take care of parametrizing the superclass, and that's where you will put all entity-specific methods.

As for Question 2 - as @Ajan points out `TWO)` will throw a different exception, but an exception nonetheless. Bah, if you move to using PersistenceContext that exception upon exiting the DAO might be wrapped by another exception which makes error handling annoying. As a rule of a thumb I would assume that no exception should be thrown from DAO methods, and even when caught within the method exception handling is still slow. I use your `ONE)` style returns.